# useState for Dropdown elements - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, use-state

### Problem

When I select an option the the dropdown menu, nothing gets selected as the value of `role` is an empty string. The UI framework used is Semantic UI.

### How the program works

When the user inputs on the Input fields the function `onChange` takes the input and savges it onto the empty string in `values`. However this is invalid when the Input type is a Dropdown Menu with predefined inputs. Hence, when the user selects any of the options it automatically gets turned to an empty string.

I am not able to understand how to solve this issue.

### The Code

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      email: '',
      role: '' // This here seems to be the issue.
  })

//OnChange Function (works for Input types)

 const onChange = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
 }

//FormInput for reference (working)

<Form.Input 
      label="Full Name"
      placeholder="Full Name"
      type="text"
      name="username"
      value={values.username}
      onChange={onChange}
/>


//DropDown menu from SemanticUI

<Dropdown
    placeholder="Select Role"
    name="role"
    fluid
    selection
    options={options}
    value={values.role}
    onChange={onChange}
/>

//Options for Dropdown Menu

const options =[
        {
            key: 'Client',
            text: 'Client',
            value: 'Client'
        },
        {
            key: 'Employee',
            text: 'Employee',
            value: 'Employee'
        }
    ]
```

Update: added `"name"=role` in the dropdown menu. However still does not work.

### Screenshot before selecting dropdown Item

[image: img1]

### Screenshot after selecting dropdown Item

[image: img2 after filled up]

Update : Added images for reference

Comment: What do you see in `e.target.name`? Can you `console.log(e.target.name)`

Comment: May it be because dropdown items don't have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Dropdown `onChange` should be something like this

```
 const onChange = (e, {value}) => {
    setValues({...values, role: value});
 }
```

Refer to controlled input demo here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled

**EDIT:** If you don't want to update your `onChange` function then perhaps this would do it.

```
<Dropdown
    placeholder="Select Role"
    fluid
    selection
    options={options}
    value={values.role}
    onChange={(e, {value}) => onChange({
     target: {name: 'role', value}
    })}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think my onChange function is the same. It takes named elements' value and adds them to useState values.

Comment: `e.target.name` is undefined, it's not gonna work for Dropdown because `e.target` represents your dropdown item

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with a form I'm making and my solution isn't DRY at all, but it works.

```html
 <select name="State" id="state" value={props.formInputs.state} onChange={props.handleChange}> 
           <option id="state" value="Alabama">AL</option>
           <option id="state" value="Alaska">AK</option>
```

For each option in the drop down, I added the `id="state"` for my `handleChange()` and it was able to then take whatever option was selected from the drop down menu and put it into my object to pass to my database.

And my change handler and `useState()` hooks are below:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
prayer_request:{
name: '',
state:'',
temptation:'',
}
})
const handleChange = (event) =>{
const updateInput = Object.assign({}, formInputs, { [event.target.id]: 
event.target.value}, )
updateFormInputs(updateInput)
}
const [requests, setRequests] = useState([])
const [formInputs, updateFormInputs] = useState({
name: '',
state: state,
temptation: state,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Role"
        name="role"
        id="role"
        fluid
        selection
        options={options}
        value={values.role}
        onChange={onChange}
    />
```

on Dropdown props:

- add name="role"
- Reason why you need to provide **"name"** prop on each form element to get value on onChange function.
- onChange functions looks **"e.target.name"**
  which is you didn't provide any "name" prop on your Dropdown Input.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work. When I select an option it turns back to empty.

Comment: can you please console log bellow on onChange function.
Let's see what are you getting when you change the dropdown options from browser.
const onChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value);
        setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
 }